# Abnormal rectangle block appears in marquee text with fading edge in android

Tags: android, textview, marquee, fading, hwui

**Why abnormal square block appears on the edge of textview ?**

when it has

- Marquee enabled with fading edge.
- The text view is set transparent.

**TextView defination**

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/mytext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:singleLine="true"  
    android:textSize="55sp" />
```

**TextView property**

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytext);
textView.setAlpha(0.7f);
```

This problem is not seen on android 4.1 but it's present on android 4.2 onwards if fading edge is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research it was bug in android framework after uploading below change it is resolved.
https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/69101/

The issue is no longer appear in latest version of android.